# Can I rollback the stock system by just installing an older image zip?

Tags: nexus-7, ota-update, 4.2-jelly-bean

I received the 4.2.x updates on my Nexus 7 and the performance has been awful.  I tried the Forever Gone hack and it helped but it's still much worse than 4.1.x.  I'm not so excited about doing a factory wipe in order to make my system almost as good as it was a month ago.

I've never tried rolling back a stock system before, is it possible to [download the official nexus image zip](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasi) and install it from CWM recovery?  Or do I have to do a more involved wiping and flashing process?  My system is stock 4.2.1 rooted and unlocked, with custom recovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use full image at recovery! It contains recovery too (CM can repair itself, but reflash of bootloader is not needed).

Use `fastboot` and flash partitions: `system`, `data`

You will lose all of your data on the tablet, but it is needed because of the different filesystem structure. Without reflashing `data` you will get a bootloop.

Answer (score 1):

You will most probably have to wipe.

This is because the data will have a different structure, as it is a major version.

If you have recovery, you can flash it to see if it works and if it doesn't, then you can wipe it.

I would suggest backing up any data you would like to keep.